# Trigonometry+inequality.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles, radicals, geometric-inequalities

I saw this question in one of my Trigonometry textbooks and I am unable to find any way to move ahead.
The question says that let $A,B$ and $C$ be the angles of a triangle, then prove that

$$ \sum_{cyc} \frac{\sqrt { \sin A}}{\sqrt { \sin B}+\sqrt { \sin C}-\sqrt { \sin A}} \ge \sqrt3 $$

Kindly tell me about a good approach to strike the question.

Comment: HINT: use that $$\sin(A)=\frac{a}{2R}$$ etc. $R$ is the radius of the circum circle

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}\geq\sqrt3.$$ 
Now, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}-a}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}-a)}=\frac{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2\sqrt{ab}-a)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(a+2\sqrt{ab})\geq\sqrt3\sum_{cyc}(2\sqrt{ab}-a)$$ or
$$(1+\sqrt3)(a+b+c)\geq2(\sqrt3-1)(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}),$$
which is true because $1+\sqrt3>2(\sqrt3-1)$ and $a+b+c\geq\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}$.

Done!